# Finding function $f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

How do we find the function(s) $f(x)$ given that $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} te^tf(x-t) \ \mathrm{d}t$$

My Try : I first used the property $\int_{0}^{a}g(x) \ \mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{a}g(a-x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ and then differentiated to find that $$f'(x)=f(x)-e^x\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t}f(t) \ \mathrm{d}t$$

Then I differentiated again to find that $$f''(x)=2f'(x)-2f(x)$$

I entered this differential equation into [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%3D2y%27-2y) and it returned

$f(x)=c_1e^x\sin x+c_2e^x\cos x$

But I don't think that this satisfies the given initial condition.

Please help me out. Hints or answers appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\int_{0}^{x} te^tf(x-t) dt
= \int_{0}^{x} (x-t)e^{x-t}f(t) dt
= xe^x\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t}f(t) dt - e^x\int_{0}^{x} te^{-t}f(t) dt
$$whose derivative is
$$
(x+1)e^x\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t}f(t) dt +  xf(x) 
- e^x\int_{0}^{x} te^{-t}f(t) dt
- xf(x)
\\= (x+1)e^x\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t}f(t) dt - e^x\int_{0}^{x} te^{-t}f(t) dt
$$

Answer (score 0):

my puzzlement arises as follows:
$$
f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} te^tf(x-t) \ \mathrm{d}x \\
f(0) = 0 \\
f'(x) = xe^xf(0) + \int_0^x te^tf'(x-t)dt=\int_0^x te^tf'(x-t)dt \\
f'(0) =0
$$
similarly 
$$
f^{(n)}(0) =0
$$
if $f$ had a Maclaurin expansion about zero then $f \equiv 0$

have i got my arithmetic wrong, or is there something peculiar at $x=0$ which forbids the Maclaurin development?

Comment: FYI you can perfectly find functions $f \in C^{\infty}$ which are non-nil on $]0,+\infty[$ and still have $\forall n, f^{(n)}(0) = 0$.

Comment: i see, and could be analytic elsewhere. would maybe  $f(x)=e^{-\frac1{x^2}}$ behave like that? thx for the explanation

Comment: From memory yes it does as all derivatives are of the form $P(x)f(x)$ with $P$ polynomial. PS: you need to define $f(0)=0$.